# ADO Jet SQL Throws "Syntax Error in FROM Clause" Always

Tags: c++, vba, ado, porting

I have an existing program written in VBA and running inside of MS Access.  For a variety of reasons, we wish to take it out of Access and make a stand alone program.

Thus I am porting VBA to C++.    The following code WORKS in VBA

```
Dim DataFile As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rstSrc As New ADODB.Recordset
DataFile.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=test.aaf;"
rstSrc.Open "SELECT * FROM [Headr];", DataFile, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

My port of the code to C++ below does NOT work.   It gives error "Syntax Error in FROM Clause" every time.

```
_RecordsetPtr RS("ADODB.Recordset");
_ConnectionPtr CON("ADODB.Connection");
CON->Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=test.aaf;","","",adConnectUnspecified);
RS->PutRefActiveConnection( CON );
RS->Open("SELECT * FROM [Headr];",vtMissing,adOpenStatic,adLockReadOnly,adCmdTable);
```

I was supsicious that the [headr] was the problem, that maybe that was some kind of macro that expands only in the Access environment.   So I tried some other SQL statements just as a test and always got the same Syntax Error in FROM clause.

I tried

SELECT MSysObjects.Name AS table_name FROM MSysObjects;

SELECT * FROM MSysObjects WHERE Type=1 AND Flags=0;

SELECT 'ASDF' AS TEST FROM DUAL;

All of those gave the same error.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the data source `test.aaf`? Access databases end in either .mdb or .accdb and require full path in Data Source reference. If this is another data source be sure your SQL syntax adheres to it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding a Command object to carry out the SELECT query.  The following code works;

```
_RecordsetPtr RS("ADODB.Recordset");
_ConnectionPtr CON("ADODB.Connection");
_CommandPtr CMD("ADODB.Command");
CON->Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=test.aaf;","","",adConnectUnspecified);
CMD->ActiveConnection = CON;
CMD->CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Headr];";
RS = CMD->Execute(NULL,NULL,0);
```

There is fundamentally no difference between this and what I was doing before.  They ought to both work equally well, just slightly different semantics.   But in reality this works and the former does not work.  So i think it is a bug in the Jet OBDC driver.